# jQuery closest() getting above row with a certain class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is a simplified example to explain what I am trying to understand, namely how to get the first row above the current row that has a certain id:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#alphabet").closest("tr']").css({"color": "white", "background-color": "green"}); // finds the same row as expected
  $("#alphabet").closest("tr#number']").css({"color": "white", "background-color": "green"});  // Does NOT find anything
  $("#alphabet").closest("tr:has([class*='num'])").css({"color": "white", "background-color": "green"}); // Does NOT find anything

});
</script>
</head>

<body >body (great-great-grandparent)
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>col 1</th>
          <th>col 2</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id='number' class="num">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='alphabet'>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

I am intentionally avoiding the use of .next(), prev().

Answer (score 2):

try:

`$("#alphabet").siblings('#number').css(...)`

Closest is for moving up the hierarchy, e.g. from td to tr, siblings for moving around same level.

Answer (score 1):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The `.parents()` and `.closest()` methods are similar in that they both traverse up the DOM tree. The differences between the two, though subtle

May be best to use `.parents()` or `.siblings()`. `.closest()` will not be able to see the element as it will have already traverse to `<tbody>` in it's first step.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#alphabet").parent().find("#number").css({
    "color": "white",
    "background-color": "green"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='number' class="num">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='alphabet'>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```